# Pandas improvement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I currently have a Pandas Dataframe in which I'm performing comparisons between columns. I found a case in which there are empty columns when comparison is taking place, comparison for some reason returns **else** value. I added an extra statement to clean it up to empty. Looking to see if I can simplify this and have a single statement.

```
df['doc_type'].loc[(df['a_id'].isnull() & df['b_id'].isnull())] = ''
```

**Code**

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a_id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '', 'F', ''],
        'a_score': [1, 2, 3, 4, '', 6, ''],
        'b_id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', ''],
        'b_score': [0.1, 0.2, 3.1, 4.1, 5, 5.99, ''],

    })
    print df
    # Replace empty string with NaN
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x).replace('', np.nan)

    # Calculate higher score
    df['doc_id'] = df.apply(lambda df: df['a_id'] if df['a_score'] >= df['b_score'] else df['b_id'], axis=1)

    # Select type based on higher score
    df['doc_type'] = df.apply(lambda df: 'a' if df['a_score'] >= df['b_score'] else 'b', axis=1)
    print df
    # Update type when is empty        
    df['doc_type'].loc[(df['a_id'].isnull() & df['b_id'].isnull())] = ''
    print df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead `apply`, also for select by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with column(s) is better use this solution:

```
df.loc[mask, 'colname'] = val
```

---

```
 # Replace empty string with NaN
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x).replace('', np.nan)

# Calculate higher score
df['doc_id'] = np.where(df['a_score'] >= df['b_score'], df['a_id'], df['b_id'])
# Select type based on higher score
df['doc_type'] = np.where(df['a_score'] >= df['b_score'], 'a', 'b')
print (df)
# Update type when is empty        
df.loc[(df['a_id'].isnull() & df['b_id'].isnull()), 'doc_type'] = ''
print (df)
  a_id  a_score b_id  b_score doc_id doc_type
0    A      1.0    a     0.10      A        a
1    B      2.0    b     0.20      B        a
2    C      3.0    c     3.10      c        b
3    D      4.0    d     4.10      d        b
4  NaN      NaN    e     5.00      e        b
5    F      6.0    f     5.99      F        a
6  NaN      NaN  NaN      NaN    NaN
```

Alternative of `mask` with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all `True` in row - `axis=1`:

```
print (df[['a_id', 'b_id']].isnull())
    a_id   b_id
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
4   True  False
5  False  False
6   True   True

print (df[['a_id', 'b_id']].isnull().all(axis=1))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
dtype: bool

df.loc[df[['a_id', 'b_id']].isnull().all(axis=1), 'doc_type'] = ''
print (df)
  a_id  a_score b_id  b_score doc_id doc_type
0    A      1.0    a     0.10      A        a
1    B      2.0    b     0.20      B        a
2    C      3.0    c     3.10      c        b
3    D      4.0    d     4.10      d        b
4  NaN      NaN    e     5.00      e        b
5    F      6.0    f     5.99      F        a
6  NaN      NaN  NaN      NaN    NaN
```

Bur better is use double `numpy.where`:

```
 # Replace empty string with NaN
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x).replace('', np.nan)

#create masks to series - not compare twice
mask = df['a_score'] >= df['b_score']
mask1 = (df['a_id'].isnull() & df['b_id'].isnull())
#altrnative solution for mask1
#mask1 = df[['a_id', 'b_id']].isnull().all(axis=1)
# Calculate higher score
df['doc_id'] = np.where(mask, df['a_id'], df['b_id'])
# Select type based on higher score
df['doc_type'] = np.where(mask, 'a', np.where(mask1, '', 'b'))
print (df)
  a_id  a_score b_id  b_score doc_id doc_type
0    A      1.0    a     0.10      A        a
1    B      2.0    b     0.20      B        a
2    C      3.0    c     3.10      c        b
3    D      4.0    d     4.10      d        b
4  NaN      NaN    e     5.00      e        b
5    F      6.0    f     5.99      F        a
6  NaN      NaN  NaN      NaN    NaN
```